# win32com has different behavior when running from * .exe or * .py

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I have a Python project developed by a colleague, in which win32com is used to control the application: CANoe from Vector.

When he is running the *.py script from PyCharm (2019.2.5) everything is ok, if he used auto-py-to-exe to convert the python script to *.exe, and then he executes the *.exe everything is ok, in both cases the script is working perfectly fine.

Now the problem is the following: if I'm trying to run the *.py script from PyCharm (2020.1.2) the module win32com is throwing an exception:

```
raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.CANoe 11.0 Type Library.ITestEnvironment instance at 0x2039251561776>' object has no attribute 'TestModules'
```

From what I checked the COM Library has 2 dispinterface: *ITestEnvironment* and *ITestEnvironment2*, and only *ITestEnvironment2* has the attribute *TestModules*, and it seems that in my case somehow the script is not considering the correct interface.

If I use auto-py-to-exe to convert the python script to *.exe, and then execute the *.exe, everything works perfectly fine. If he converts the script to *.exe and then I run it on my PC, or I convert locally the script to *.exe and run it on my PC, in both cases the out of the script is the same.

I tried:

- Install the same PyCharm version as he uses
- Run the code from Visual Studio 2017
- Update pywin32 to latest version (228)

in all the cases the result is the same.

I'm using the same Python version as he uses: Py 3.6.7.

Dose anyone know why ***win32com*** has different behavior when running from * .exe or * .py, and also why it has different behavior on different PCs ?

Comment: Questions on this site are expected to contain an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example). If you suspect a generic issue like what you wrote in the title, try it with a minimal COM library and improve the question. Chances are, by the time you have an MCVE you also have the answer, but then you might be able to post both a good question and a good answer for it.

Comment: @V-R From my point of view in this case no code example is needed. As the main idea of the question is: if someone else encountered this behavior with win32com when executed from *.exe or .py, even if is when using any other COM library.